# Speed up app launch

Tags: kubuntu

I bought new notebook (Acer Aspire F15 / F5-573-56GH) with Win 10 (64b, 8GB RAM, Intel I5), where just after clicking icon (Chrome, FF, File manager, everything) it appeared (the app or app init screen - like Gimp) almost at that moment.

After hours messing up with installation of Kubuntu 16.04 (which didn't work with UEFI, I had to set BIOS Legacy) to replace Win 10, I have to wait after click on any app launcher, and wait about 3sec. before it could be used. Is there any way to speed up apps launch? I think there must be some delay set in system?

Comment: Try to install `preload`, it will cache frequently used programs in memory after booting so that they start up faster. No configuration needed, just run `sudo apt install preload`.

Comment: I'll give it a try. How long does it need to start working (as it's "cache")?

Comment: I don't know. It adapts what gets preloaded to your usage statistics, so it will surely need a bit of time to learn what you use frequently.

Comment: Could also be an issue with slow graphics. Are other desktop animations fluid and did you install the proper graphics drivers for you GPU?